# template matching with two images that differ in color

Tags: python, opencv, template-matching

I'm looking to

1: detect a button

2: determine a winner based on color of the button

It seems like template matching is what I should be doing, but that works in greyscale. The buttons im detecting are green and red, but look pretty much identical when grayscale. my idea was if I subtract two color channels out of the image and the two templates that when I convert everything to grayscale the two template images will look different and result in diverging scores.

In practice it isnt really working out that way. I've fiddled quite a bit with this and either both templates score very high, or they dont detect the button properly at all. I can't get a divergence.

I'm brand new to OpenCV, so it's possible my approach is just not good. It's equally likely what I'm writing is not doing what I think it is. Let me know what you think. I've included my code and the source images I'm using.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

dire = cv2.imread('dire.jpg')
dire_template = cv2.imread('dire_template.jpg')
radiant = cv2.imread('radiant.jpg')
radiant_template = cv2.imread('radiant_template.jpg')

# color images are in the form BGR
# removing the B and G from the images makes the "continue" button more distinct between the two teams
# since dire is red while radiant is green
dire_red = dire.copy()
dire_red[:,:,0] = 0
dire_red[:,:,1] = 0

dire_template_red = dire_template.copy()
dire_template_red[:,:,0] = 0
dire_template_red[:,:,1] = 0

radiant_red = radiant.copy()
radiant_red[:,:,0] = 0
radiant_red[:,:,1] = 0

radiant_template_red = radiant_template.copy()
radiant_template_red[:,:,0] = 0
radiant_template_red[:,:,1] = 0


dire_gray = cv2.cvtColor(dire_red, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
dire_template_gray = cv2.cvtColor(dire_template_red, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
radiant_gray = cv2.cvtColor(radiant_red, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
radiant_template_gray = cv2.cvtColor(radiant_template_red, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# plt.figure(0)
# plt.imshow(dire_red)
# plt.figure(1)
# plt.imshow(radiant_red)
# plt.figure(2)
# plt.imshow(dire_gray, cmap='gray')
# plt.figure(3)
# plt.imshow(radiant_gray, cmap='gray')
# plt.figure(4)
# plt.imshow(dire_template_red)
# plt.figure(5)
# plt.imshow(radiant_template_red)
# plt.figure(6)
# plt.imshow(dire_template_gray)
# plt.figure(7)
# plt.imshow(radiant_template_gray, cmap='gray')

# plt.show()

w, h = dire_template_gray.shape[::-1]

# All the 6 methods for comparison in a list
methods = ['cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED', 
            'cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED', 'cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED']

for meth in methods:
    print(f'{meth}: ')
    # this would be the live image
    img = dire_gray.copy()
    method = eval(meth)

    # Apply template Matching
    dire_res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,dire_template_gray,method)
    radiant_res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,radiant_template_gray,method)


    dire_vals = [min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc] = cv2.minMaxLoc(dire_res)
    radiant_vals = [min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc] = cv2.minMaxLoc(radiant_res)

    print(dire_vals)
    print(radiant_vals)
    # print(f'min val: {min_val} max val: {max_val}')

    # If the method is TM_SQDIFF or TM_SQDIFF_NORMED, take minimum
    if method in [cv2.TM_SQDIFF, cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED]:
        top_left = min_loc
    else:
        top_left = max_loc
    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)

    cv2.rectangle(img,top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)

    # plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(res,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(dire_res)
    plt.title('Matching Result'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    # plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(img)
    plt.title('Detected Point'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.suptitle(meth)

    plt.show()
```

[image: radiant.jpg]
[image: dire.jpg]
[image: radiant_template.jpg]
[image]

Comment: Find the location in grayscale. Once you know where the button is, go back to BGR (or even HSV) and determine the colour.

Comment: do you want to detect both buttons with same code or do you want to distinguish them? What about shape matching of the edges like chamfer matching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach seems exactly how you should be implementing it. I did the same approach and this is my result:

Step 1: Load images in color and get gray scaled

```
img_red = cv2.imread("red.jpg")
img_red_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_red, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

img_green = cv2.imread("green.jpg")
img_green_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_green, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

// template is required only in gray
template = cv2.imread("template.jpg", 0)
```

Step 2: Get size of template and perform template matching

```
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
method = cv2.TM_CCOEFF
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_red_gray, template, method)
```

Step 3: Get template location in image and get its mean color intensity

```
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
top_left = max_loc
color = cv2.mean(img_red[top_left[1]:top_left[1] + h, top_left[0]:top_left[0]+w])
```

Additional: To draw the match in the main image

```
bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
cv2.rectangle(img_red_gray, top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)
```

Results:

[image: Template in Green]

[image: Template in Red]

Red Image Color = `(5.1372107567229515, 12.502939337085678, 72.62376485303315, 0.0)` **(B, G, R, A)**

Green Image Color = `(63.20187617260788, 85.38574108818011, 49.76873045653534, 0.0)` **(B, G, R, A)**

As @Dan suggested, you can also do this in HSV to get higher differences.

You can see clearly that now you can say with the single channel values if the template in the image is green or red.
Hope it helps!